# How to check a wallet's Wrapped Ether balance on OpenSea or Etherscan?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, wallets, etherscan, wrapped-tokens

Etherscan shows transfers in and out of Ether, whereas Wrapped Ether (WETH) appears in Etherscan's ERC-20 transactions.

Etherscan readily displays the current Ether balance of a wallet at the top-left of the page, but how to see a wallet's WETH balance?

If not visible on Etherscan, is the WETH balance visible to others besides the user on OpenSea somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go on the [WETH contract page](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2?a=0x77f0decba8a2200c49ba5b1c2fc5d85d0c608e2d#readContract).

In the contract tab, go to read contract and make a call to the balanceOf function with the address you wish to get the balance of.

[image]

Comment: In the scenario that the contract isn't an ERC-20 like WETH, but instead an open edition (multiple copy) ERC-721 NFT, how can someone extract a list of all holders of that contract/NFT, for either or?

Comment: For NFT  you could iterate over the events that were emitted during the lifespan of the contract. Not sure if there is another easier way

Comment: Nothing on the Etherscan above, for the ERC-20, gives a list of holders of the fungible token?

Comment: No it's not part of the ERC-20 interface as far as I know of. You can also rely on the events to get such a list at any point in time.